# Re-deploying a Rails app without overwriting the production database (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, heroku, production

I've got a Rails 4 app, hosted on Heroku. I'm running it in production already, and want to be able to make improvements to the app periodically, **without** touching the production database.

(There's user-generated data in the live app already, and my improvements are to the logic and design, not the database).

Am I correct in thinking that if I re-deploy the app with `git push heroku master` after each modification then the data in the production db will remain intact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, redeployment will not alter your database.

Answer (score 2):

Only the app code changes. The database is completely different and thus remains intact.